# Videos in posts are not rendered

Tags: videos

I have a wordpress website, but the blog/post side of things wont display videos even when using the insert media/video link.

It just shows the code up.

What page/file do I need to edit and where to get this to work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this line where you want to display the video:

```
<iframe width="604" height="453" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/your_video_id?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

replacing "your_video_id" with your id (find it in your youtube account).

Comment: Interesting, that works however Im certain I tried that in the past and got nowhere! Thanks!

Comment: I think this is not a proper answer. Wordpress offer shortcodes and auto-embed features for a wide range of video providers, including youtube. Also, direct embeding is considered a bad practice in editorial area. You should definitely use the youbute url and wordpress will render the vídeo for you, if this feature is not working you should investigate the reason instead of directly paste the embeding code.

Comment: The problem was that it was not rendering the video for me, but the above solution is doing.

Comment: I would suggest that the *symptom* was that WordPress was not rendering the video; the *problem* is still unfound.